# Combining two queries together to form month count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have the following query:

```
select 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear, count(*) as Count
from 
    visit
where 
    StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    and clientid = 142
group by  
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)
```

which returns the following results:

```
+-------------------------+----+
| 2015-12-01 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 13 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 |  1 |
| 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 22 |
| 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 22 |
| 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 25 |
| 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 36 |
+-------------------------+----+
```

I also have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (12) 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - test, 0) as        MonthYear
FROM
    test
```

which returns the following results:

```
+-------------------------+
| 2016-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2015-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2015-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

What I need to do is combine the two queries into one query and show **0** for those months that are missing from the original query.

Could someone help please?

Comment: u can keep union all between 2 queries

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that, I get duplicate rows.

Comment: then keep union

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: see i want to know select query 1 will returns duplicates  and query 2 will returns  duplicates if they wont return duplicates u can keep union 
union will not return duplicates

Comment: Can you provide sample data to test the query

Comment: create table test2
(
 startdate datetime
)

insert into test2 
(
 startdate
)
values
(
 '01 Jan 2016'
)
insert into test2 
(
 startdate
)
values
(
 '05 Jan 2016'
)
insert into test2 
(
 startdate
)
values
(
 '14 Mar 2016'
)
insert into test2 
(
 startdate
)
values
(
 '18 April 2016'
)

Comment: Basically the query should show February too in the results.

Comment: In your Post what is the different between visit table and the test table are they actually supposed to be the same table? Will all dates actually be represented in the visit table if is NOT constrained by the clientid? If so simple conditional aggregation could be an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be doing a lot of gaps and island calculation and or date based queries without gaps then I cannot stress how much simpler a Calendar table will make your life.

Basically, all you need is a table similar to:

**Calender**

```
    Day INT,
    Month INT, 
    Year INT, 
    StartOfDay DATETIME,
    EndOfDay DATETIME,
    DayOfWeek INT, 
    WeekInyear INT, 
    IsWeekDay BIT
```

Pick a date range. I chose this century and last century as it fits my business models needs. Next, simply run a loop function once and populate your table, finally apply proper indexes and use as needed.

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME ='01/01/2015'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME   ='01/01/2017' 

DECLARE @MONTHS TABLE(Month INT,Year INT)

WHILE @BeginDate<=@EndDate BEGIN
    INSERT @Months SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,@BeginDate),DATEPART(YEAR,@BeginDate)
    SET @BeginDate=DATEADD(MONTH,1,@BeginDate)
END

SELECT 
    Calendar.Month,
    Calendar.Year,
    COUNT(visit.userID) 
FROM 
    @Months Calendar
    LEFT JOIN visit ON visit.year=Calendar.Year AND visit.Month=Calendar.Month
GROUP BY
    Calendar.Month,
    Calendar.Year
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion there. That seems to make the most sense with a calendar table and helps me with other queries also.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally this is solved with a calendar table (eg [this msdn answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb0ca2f5-52a3-4ad3-8d08-e553c7235285/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-calendar-informationappointments-db-vs?forum=databasedesign])), but in your case a derived table and outer join should work:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear,count(*) as Count
    from (SELECT TOP (12) DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-test, 0) as MonthYear
  from test) cal LEFT OUTER JOIN visit on (cal.MonthYear = visit.MonthYear)
    where StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    and clientid = 142
    group by  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks GHWP, appreciate that. One issue though is in the join visit.MonthYear.  That field doesn't exist and is calculated through the following: DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0). But I can't add that to the join. Could you advise please?

Comment: When you `select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear` you are aliasing that column, so you can refer to it later by name.You can join to this calculated column using i

Comment: ...using the name 'MonthYear' and similarly you can use the alias inyour group by clasue too.

Comment: I think I may have miscommunicated myself sorry. I was referring to this part of the query: LEFT OUTER JOIN visit on (cal.MonthYear = visit.MonthYear)  visit.MonthYear doesn't exist and is a calculated value.

Comment: That should work fine.  Because you've given the calculated column a name ('MonthYear'), you can refer to it by that name in other places in the query - including join statements.  The column doesn't exist in the table, but it does exist in the query - that's what the 'as xxx' syntax is used for.

Comment: Oh, it's saying Invalid column name 'MonthYear'. when I run the query and it points at this line   from test) cal LEFT OUTER JOIN visit on (cal.MonthYear = visit.MonthYear) because the visit table does not contain MonthYear.

Comment: Try the syntax `LEFT OUTER JOIN using (MonthYear)`

Comment: Failing that: `Select MonthYear, count(*) from ( SELECT TOP (12) DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-test, 0) as        MonthYear
  from test ) cal LEFT OUTER JOIN
( select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear
    from visit
    where StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    and clientid = 142 ) v using (MonthYear)
GROUP BY cal.MonthYear
`

Comment: Thanks GHWP, I get this though:
102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'using'.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses CROSS APPLY with VALUES to create your Master Month List.

I recommend replacing GETDATE() with a variable if you can.

```
CREATE TABLE #Visit(StartDate DATE,clientid int)

INSERT INTO #Visit VALUES
('20160304',142)
,('20160305',142)
,('20160508',142)
,('20160612',142)
,('20160617',142)

SELECT 
    T.Mnth
    ,COUNT(V.StartDate) AS [Count]
FROM 
     (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) c (test)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - c.test, 0) Mnth) T 
        LEFT JOIN #Visit V
            ON
            DATEDIFF(MM,V.startdate,T.Mnth) = 0
            AND StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
            AND clientid = 142
GROUP BY
    T.Mnth
ORDER BY 
    T.Mnth DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of subqueries with a `LEFT JOIN` and an `ISNULL` should do it:

```
SELECT sub1.MonthYear,
       ISNULL(sub2.Count, 0)
FROM
(SELECT TOP (12) DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - test, 0) AS MonthYear
 FROM test t) sub1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear,
        COUNT(*) AS Count
 FROM visit
 WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
   AND clientid = 142
 GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)) sub2
ON sub1.MonthYear = sub2.MonthYear
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use a TVF to create dynamic date/time ranges.  This udf is faster than the recursive cte approach (especially on larger sets).  Furthermore, you get to define the date range, datepart, and increment.  I should note, a tally table would do the trick as well.

```
-- Generate Some Sample Data
Declare @Visit table (StartDate date,Cnt int)
Insert Into @Visit values
('2015-12-01 00:00:00.000', 1),
('2016-02-01 00:00:00.000',13),
('2016-03-01 00:00:00.000', 1),
('2016-04-01 00:00:00.000',22),
('2016-05-01 00:00:00.000',22),
('2016-06-01 00:00:00.000',25),
('2016-07-01 00:00:00.000',36)

-- Set Key Dates
Declare @DateR2 date = '2016-10-01'
Declare @DateR1 date = DateAdd(YY,-1,@DateR2)

-- Execute Query
Select DateR1
      ,Cnt    = isnull(sum(Cnt),0)
 From  (Select DateR1=RetVal,DateR2=DateAdd(MM,1,RetVal)-1 From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](@DateR1,@DateR2,'MM',1)) A
 Left  Join @Visit B on B.StartDate Between A.DateR1 and A.DateR2
 Group By DateR1
 Order by DateR1
```

Returns

```
Period      Cnt
2015-10-01  0
2015-11-01  0
2015-12-01  1
2016-01-01  0
2016-02-01  13
2016-03-01  1
2016-04-01  22
2016-05-01  22
2016-06-01  25
2016-07-01  36
2016-08-01  0
2016-09-01  0
2016-10-01  0
```

---

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cteCalendar as 
(
  SELECT TOP (12) 
      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - test, 0) as        MonthYear
  FROM
      test
),
cteVisits as
(
  select 
      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear, count(*) as Count
  from 
      visit
  where 
      StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
      and clientid = 142
  group by  
      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)
)
SELECT
  c.MonthYear,
  ISNULL(v.Count, 0) as VisitCount
FROM cteCalendar c
LEFT JOIN cteVisits v
ON v.MonthYear = c.MonthYear
ORDER BY c.MonthYear
```

Answer (score 0):

so there are a lot of answers and good ones about how to create a MONTH table then left join your visits to get to your answer.  But I just wanted to show you how conditional Aggregation could assist you if there will always be at least 1 date from each month in the visit table.  Note, I do not mean 1 record for the client you are filtering but rather for any/all clients.  In other words will there be at least 1 client in every month?  If so you can do conditional aggregation to get to answer like so:

```
select 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear
    ,count(CASE WHEN clientid = 142 THEN clientid END) as Count
from 
    visit
where 
    StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
group by  
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)
```

If not then yep you will need a date table [@pacreely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949355/5510627) shows you a nice method of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

you can format the query as follows

```
;with CTE AS (select 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear, count(*) as Count
from 
    visit
where 
    StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    and clientid = 142
group by  
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)

)
, cte2 AS(
SELECT TOP (12) 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - test, 0) as        MonthYear
FROM
    test )

    SELECT ISNULL(cte.MonthYear, cte2.MonthYear) AS MonthYear , ISNULL(cte.Count, 0) as Count
    from cte FULL OUTER join cte2 on cte.MonthYear = cte2.MonthYear
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @Dates table(date datetime, count int)

select 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear, count(*) as Count
    into @Dates
from 
    visit
where 
    StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    and clientid = 142
group by  
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)

    SELECT TOP (12) 
    into @Dates
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - test, 0) as        MonthYear,0
FROM
    test

    select * from @Dates
```

Answer (score -1):

After assuming that the "test" table is a table listing the first of each month for at least the past year and may include future dates as well, here is my suggestion:

```
With VisitList as
(SELECT 
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0) as MonthYear, count(*) as VisitCount
FROM visit
WHERE
StartDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
and clientid = 142
GROUP BY  
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartDate), 0)

UNION

SELECT testDate, 0 AS VisitCount 
FROM test
WHERE testDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())

SELECT MonthYear, Sum(VisitCount) AS VisitCount FROM VisitList
GROUP BY MonthYear
ORDER BY MonthYear DESC
```